# How can I use variables with .htaccess Redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So, I have a local URL `/go/xxx` where `xxx` is any string or number of the user's choice. I'd like to redirect that to `/handlers/Redirect?q=xxx`, and again, `xxx` being that variable.

I tried using `Redirect`, but I had no successor.

```
Redirect /go/$ /handlers/Redirect.html?q=$
```

I, then, read that you can't have variables in `Redirect` and should use `mod_redirect`. I did that, and still had no successor.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^go/$ handlers/Redirect.html?q=$
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong and what I have to do to make it redirect correctly?

**Conclusion/example**: Redirect from `https://example.com/go/support` to `https://example.com/handlers/Redirect.html?q=support`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way but you are checking %{QUERY_STRING} and you should check %{REQUEST_URI}.

Check this short rule ( rewrite /go/anything <> /handlers/Redirect.html?q=anything ):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^go\/(.*)$ /handlers/Redirect.html?q=$1 [L]
```